# openssl DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt encounter Use of uninitialised value of size 8

Tags: openssl

use c++ invoke openssl crypto lib get error message,flow line:

> ==8752== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
>
> ==8752==    at 0x4EC3279: DES_encrypt2 (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
>
> ==8752==    by 0x4EC3A6E: DES_encrypt3 (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
>
> ==8752==    by 0x4EC43C2: DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
>
> ==8752==    by 0x403808: des3Encrypt (xcode.c:454)
>
> ==8752==    by 0x402A60: main (server.c:428)

and source code:

```
int des3Encrypt(unsigned char *Out,char *Key1,char *Key2,char *Key3, char *Msg, int size)
{

    unsigned char*    Res;

    DES_cblock key1, key2, key3;

    DES_cblock ivsetup = {'\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0','\0', '\0', '\0'};
    DES_cblock ivec;
    DES_key_schedule ks1, ks2, ks3;

    memcpy(&key1,Key1,8);
    memcpy(&key2,Key2,8);
    memcpy(&key3,Key3,8);

    DES_set_key((DES_cblock *)key1, &ks1);
    DES_set_key((DES_cblock *)key2, &ks2);
    DES_set_key((DES_cblock *)key3, &ks3);

    int len =size ;
    /*
    short spure=len%8;
    printf("3des encode add bit before:%d,",len);

    if(spure!=0  ){
            len=(len+8-spure);
    }
    printf("after:%d\n",len);
    */

    Res=(unsigned char * ) malloc(len*sizeof(unsigned char));
    if(!Res) return 0;
    unsigned char * InBuffer=(unsigned char * ) malloc(len*sizeof( unsigned char));
    if(!InBuffer) return 0;
    bzero( InBuffer, len);
    memcpy( InBuffer,Msg,size );
    memcpy(ivec, ivsetup, sizeof(ivsetup));
    if(InBuffer == NULL || Res == NULL || ivec == NULL)
    {
            printf("uninitialised failed.\n");
    }
    DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt(InBuffer, Res, len, &ks1, &ks2, &ks3, &ivec, DES_ENCRYPT); <<<< this is 454 line
    free( InBuffer );
    memcpy(Out,Res,len);
    bzero( Res, len);
    free(Res);
    Res = NULL;

    return len;
}
```

please help me,3ks.

Comment: Did you compile the library and your program with `-O0` or `-O1` per [The Valgrind Quick Start Guide](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html)? You are probably not going to be able to use `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so` because it was likely compiled with `-O2` or `-O3`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it does not solve your problem you have to initialize the padded bytes by the value of what you call spure in your code. So if for example if you are trying to add 3 bytes to the end of the input to make len % 8 == 0 then the bytes you actually add to the end of the input should be 333. See about padding here https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding also you should zero ivec memset(&ivec, 0, sizeof(ivec));